# Can data be changed in my tables that will break batch updating while it modifies multiple rows?

Tags: concurrency, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an update query that is based on the result of a select, typically returning more than 1000 rows.

If some of these rows are updated by other queries before this update can touch them could that cause a problem with the records? For example could they get out of sync with the original query?

If so would it be better to select and update individual rows rather than in batch?

If it makes a difference, the query is being run on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks.

Comment: The version of SQL you are using actually does not matter here - all such SQL systems should have similar protection for this type of change. (NoSQL, however, may be different...)

Comment: Question... when you say "if some of these rows are updated", are you referring to the selected rows or the rows being updated?

Comment: It would also help to see your SQL statements

Comment: Agree. Please post your SQL so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

No.

A Table cannot be updated while something else is in the process of updating it.

Databases use concurrency control and have ACID properties to prevent exactly this type of problem.

Comment: Well, to be explicit, it may still be possible that the lock has not escalated to a table lock, so two different update statements could affect different rows without tripping over each other. But in most scenarios one update would win, and the other update would have to wait. And in most cases, you *want* this behavior.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - SQL server has a default isolation level that will prevent this in most cases. Unless he's doing things that would screw with concurrency and isolation levels, it will not be a problem, and given the question, I assume that the questioner is not.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading up on [isolation levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).  The default in SQL Server is `READ COMMITTED`, which means that other transactions cannot read data that has been updated but not committed by a given transaction.

This means that data returned by your select/update statement will be an accurate reflection of the database at a moment in time.

If you were to change your database to `READ UNCOMMITTED` then you could get into a situation where the data from your select/update is out of synch.

Answer (score -1):

If you're selecting first, then updating, you can use a transaction

```
BEGIN TRAN

-- your select WITHOUT LOCKING HINT

-- your update based upon select

COMMIT TRAN
```

However, if you're updating directly from a select, then, no need to worry about it.  A single transaction is implied.

```
UPDATE mytable
  SET value = mot.value
FROM myOtherTable mot
```

BUT... do NOT do the following, otherwise you'll run into a deadlock

```
UPDATE mytable
  SET value = mot.value
FROM myOtherTable mot WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: I didn't -1 but just for clarity it is an update not an insert